# Cordova not copy fonts when generate APK

Tags: android, cordova

I use Cordova 8.0 and it is my www project tree:

[image]

When I run `cordova run android` for test my app in my phone I get the next project tree:

[image]

(I show it thanks to Chrome Dev Tools)

So cordova completely omited my fonts folder How can I avoid it?

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the font folder?

Comment: chrome dev tools shows only what was loaded. do you include the font in html/css? the path inside the css @import might needs to be changed. check also the network tap in chrome dev tools if the file request is there and what is the reason that it was not loaded.

Comment: @Stefan I added image of the error.

Comment: the error is like i mentioned. the fonts folder is there, but on the false location as your css @import has a different path... check the path of the network tap it says: `.../css/static/fonts/...`. either you change the css @import path or copy the fonts folder inside the `css/static` folder

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your help, finaly I think the problem is because I use Webpack for bundle my App and it have problems under file:// protocol, for solve my problem I manualy change the route of the compiling .css (that import  the font) and it works.